# xamarin android ,Keyboard Scroll?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a login form in my app. If the Entry is entered, the keyboard open.

But the problem is, that I can't scroll. So I have to close the keyboard to enter the other entry. This is not good!

Has anybody a solution for me?

Comment: Put your login view inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gabe Sechan said, you can add them to the **ScrollView**, so that you can fully achieve the effect you want.

I wrote an example for you to give you a clearer reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="150" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry Placeholder="mytest"></Entry>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Label Text="mytest"></Label>
                <Entry Placeholder="mytest"></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```